# Using regex to capture everything between two asterisks

Tags: c#, regex

I'm exporting several issues from JIRA and just like SO, they utilize asterisks to deal with formatting. I'm looking to keep that formatting in when put into a word document however, there are several times where the asterisks are providing me with issues. I currently have a regular expression that works to get text between two asterisks:

`(\*.+?\*)`

This regular expression will match a significant set of the items that I'm looking at:

`*This is a bolded sentence*. This is not. *This is again.*`

Matching:

> **This is a bolded sentence**
> **This is again**

However, when I want to check a sentence as follows:

`*Set the dropdown to (*.docx) and click 'Save'*. Do the next thing.`

It will only match:

> **Set the dropdown to (**

Is there a way that I can match based on what follows? For example, if there is an asterisk period and space or a way to specify avoiding an asterisk period letter then it would match:

> **Set the dropdown to (*.docx) and click 'Save'**

I have tried modifying the current regex that I have but cannot seem to find something that works. Even when using a negated sets `[^*.]` and negative look-ahead `(?!\*\.)`.

Comment: [`\*.*?\*(?!\.\b)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c*.*%3f%5c*%28%3f!%5c.%5cb%29&i=*Set+the+dropdown+to+%28*.docx%29+and+click+%27Save%27*.+Do+the+next+thing.)?

Comment: The problem is that you are using a delimiter (a pair of asterisks) where the delimiter can be used as just text.  If you skip embedded asterisks, then your `This is a bolded sentence...` example would likely get only a single result instead of two.  If your "sentences" always ended with a period (before the asterisk), then you could look for "`.*'".  I'm pretty sure you will need to include more information about how the substrings to be captured should be delimited to get this to work.  There's a reason macro languages tend to use weird {{characters}} or $(sequences) in their identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with a negative lookahead after closing `*` to fail the match when we have a dot and non-space character after `*`:

```
\*.*?\*(?!\.\S)
```

[RegEx Demo](http://%5C*.*?%5C*(?!%5C.%5CS))

- `(?!\.\S)` is a negative lookahead to assert failure when there is a dot followed by non-whitespace character right after closing `*`